# How to retrieve 'attr_accessor' attribute names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, attr-accessor

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to retrieve all `attr_accessor` attribute names starting with a specific string. That is,

... in my module I have:

```
attr_accessor :prefix_attribute_name1,
              :prefix_attribute_name2,
              :prefix_attribute_name3,
              ...
              :attribute_name1,
              :attribute_name2,
              ...
```

and *I would like to retrieve all `attr_accessor` attribute names that starts with the `:prefix` string.* **How can I do that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, `attr_accessor` just creates accessor methods and doesn't have any particular hooks for reflection like that. If you need such a thing you could either write an extension that wraps around `attr_accessor` with `alias_method_chain` or you can just make do with this:

```
(MyClass.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods).grep(/^prefix/).sort
```

Comment: Works for Ruby < 1.9. After that, `instance_methods` returns an array of symbols, which you have to convert to string first

Comment: @tadman I should retrieve only "setter" methods from the array of symbols generated using your code. How can I do that?

Comment: @Chubas For whatever reason you can `grep` arrays of Symbols in Ruby 1.9 which is handy for this very reason.

Comment: Setter methods always end with `=`, so you just need to adjust your regexp or do a second pass to extract them: `.grep(/\=$/)`

Comment: @tadman Nice, I just checked in the documentation and `grep` uses `===` to determine match (and for some reason `Regexp === Symbol` is defined), I didn't know that. http://railsapi.com/doc/ruby-v1.9.2/classes/Enumerable.html#M000850 Learned something new, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

You can grab it using YourClass.instance_methods.select{|i| i.to_s =~ /prefix_/}.